# Factory bot for type column in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model name `collaborator`.
Collaborator fields are:(id, type, created_at, updated_at)

Also I have two more model `Manager` and `Guest`.

Both `Manager` and `Guest` extends the `Collaborator` model. So collaborator type field can only have two values either `Manager` or `Guest`.

So while writing factories for collaborator model. I got stuck.

```
FactoryBot.define do
factory :collaborator do
  #what to keep
  type { '' }
end
```

end

So what to write for the type column. So it can take either take manager or guest.

Comment: Is `type` not a reserved keyword used by rails ? How did you manage do create a model with field `type` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do something like this

```
factory :collaborator do

  factory :manager, class: Manager do
    type "manager"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a more common type. You can always overwrite this attribute when creating a collaborator: `create(:collaborator , type: 'manager')`.

Or you can define 2 more factories - one for manager and one for guest, just like:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :collaborator do
    factory :manager, class: Manager do
      type { 'manager' }
    end

    factory :guest, class: Guest do
      type { 'guest' }
    end
  end
end
```